# Resources for finding cycling partners

Tags: planning, group-rides

I'm currently preparing to cycle the TransAmerica Trail next year, but don't have anyone to go with yet. Although I've been cycling for a couple years now, I'm still quite unknowledgeable when it comes to internet groups and/or major cycling societies, in where it may be fairly easy to find someone (or multiple people) to accompany me on such a long trip.

My question is: **are there any reputable & active websites/organizations/resources that specifically help facilitate the act of searching for & finding cycling partners?**

I'm aware of local groups, but this seems to be an exhaustive and not too dependable way of finding someone. BTW, I currently live in KY (which isn't exactly known for cycling, thus making even local resources fairly limited). Any insight is greatly appreciated.. I don't want to go alone!! :(

Comment: Local bike shops.  Some have bulletin boards, or simply ask.

Comment: Facebook is another option, not that I even have an account there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to your local bike shops and ask them about group rides, local cycling associations, that sort of thing. If there's not one really "local" to you, find the best one you can find in your part of the state.
- The [ACA](https://www.adventurecycling.org) runs organized tours that you could join. Obviously money is involved. They may also know of some other resources.
- There are other tour operators that run tours on the TransAm route.
- Crazy Guy on a Bike has a listing of [community resources](http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/resources/categories/?o=1mr&category_id=19&page=1&sub_locales=1), and if you haven't checked out that website in general, make yourself a nice pot of tea and get comfortable.
- Finding someone to ride with is not going to be easy, since *not only* do they need to be able to take time off at exactly the same time as you, they *also* need to share your daily distance goals, interests in going off-route, ideas about where to stay, where to tarry, etc. I'm not saying you shouldn't try, but be realistic about all the factors involved, and don't be too put out if you come up dry. Joining an existing tour may prove easier.

I rode the Southern Tier solo. It's entirely doable that way, although I'll admit it got lonely at times.

Comment: I will comment on other aspects of your response momentarily, however, for now, can you tell me -- isn't it somewhat dangerous to travel such a distance alone? For trips like TAT, where the path is quite popular, do you think I'll run into other cyclists, and can run with them for a day or two, here and there? I do like the idea of going alone, or with one other person. This is kind of a character building/soul searching trip. On a separate note, what are your plans for mid May to late July? =P

Comment: It's probably somewhat dangerous to travel such a distance, period. Having a partner along means they can call the meatwagon when something bad happens to you, I guess. With the Southern Tier, there are a couple times of year that are popular times to ride it; I assume that's true with the TAT. I encountered other riders every few days. I already have plans for May.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on that particular route. Based on my experience, you have the following options:

- Google for the route you want to cycle, and see if there are any forums/sites dedicated to that particular route. I did it for my trip in Japan, and found a bonanza of sites, facebook groups and forums.
- search for "limited scope" travel companions: if the route you want to cover is normally done cyclists, you have high chances of finding other lonely travellers along the road. Based on your pace you can decide to share the route together. This however requires you to be willing to take the risk of travelling alone.
- Search for local association which may provide fellow cyclists for some of the route.